# Переобучение в data mining

Tags: машинное-обучение

Здравствуйте знатоки машинного обучения , у меня вопрос по поводу переобучения классификаторов, как понять что модель переобучается , какие приемы можно использовать чтобы избежать переобучения , если есть статьи или годная литература то пожалуйста скиньте, сам я не особо шарю в машинном обучении.

Comment: Статьи и литература, которые предлагают поисковые системы по запросу «переобучение», чем-то не устроили?

Comment: andreymal , я не нахожу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Алексей, переобучение происходит просто из - за того, что обучающая выборка слишком мала, и нейросеть с легкостью "запоминает" её, не пытаясь найти какую - то закономерность. Для борьбы с этим достаточно просто использовать большое количество материалов для обучения нейронной сети.
В гугле информации много, поищи там, если хочешь.